List of Tables into ForEach Loop Container, I want to use these as a Source and insert them into different Destination tables that exist
I'm trying to use SSIS to handle this (what I thought would be basic) request.
This is what I have set up:

Source connection
Destination connection
I have a list of tables in an Execute SQL Task that I'm using to populate a variable object called TableList.
I have added a Foreach Loop Container and mapped a variable called TableName that is being populated by TableList.

I have successfully executed a TRUNCATE TABLE ? SQL Task to test the package against multiple tables in the destination.
What I would like to do is use the TableName variable as a Source and Destination table for some sort of data flow. The source table is just a table heap full of data, no structure. The destination has the same exact columns but identity definitions, indexes etc.
Is there a way I can loop through this table list and set this up without creating separate data flow tasks per table?

I have looked to try to create dynamic data flows before (as you are looking to do) and I found some examples online but they were complicated and difficult to implement.  So instead of using the data flow task I created a C# script task to handle this.  Basically wrote my own data flow inside C#.  That was not super straight forward but I think it would be easier than trying to implement a dynamic data flow task.

Yea I found some very custom stuff that like you said would be difficult to implement and maintain. What I ended up doing was creating a linked server from the destination to the source and a stored proc that dynamically generates insert scripts based on a table name variable. The stored proc handles the truncate, the identity inserts, temporal tables etc and I just pass that through the SSIS foreach loop.
